# Radio Buttons within Items Control display

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Could someone please asssit with the below items control as I need my Radio buttons to be Horizontal not vertical

```
<ItemsControl Name="rbQuestionAnswer" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers, Mode=TwoWay}"    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"  >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding SurveyLineID}"
                                 Content="{Binding Answer}" 
                                 Tag="{Binding AnswerId}"               
                                 Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"            
                                 Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
                                 Visibility="{Binding Path=IsRadio,Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}" >
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add the below within the Items control:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `<StackPanel/>` to do this. Try the following code.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding AnswerId}" Content="{Binding Option}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

Modify this code to suit your requirements. Hope, it may help you!

Comment: Tried this but the layout is still the same